# What is the recommended version of Java for Windows 7?

Tags: java, windows, windows-7

Can someone advice which is the recommended version of Java Runtime Environment for Windows 7, since older version may have some incompatibilities etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [release notes](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/webnotes/6u18.html) for Java 6 Update 18 state that Windows 7 support was added. This is the latest version.

Answer (score 5):

The most current?

Go to [java.com](http://java.com) and it will tell you which one you should get.

Answer (score 1):

No need to worry about OS. If you want to use latest technology and grow with java world you should upgrade your JDK version to latest.